# Does cassandra loads whole partition in memory when for a read within partition?

Tags: cassandra

The question is pretty simple, as i want to know how cassandra reads inside the partition? Does it loads the whole partition in memory from disk?

What will be the effect if the partition size is very big?

Is the complexity of reading data in partition is O(Log(N)) in partition (where N being the total number of rows in partition) as it uses the sorted map?

SCENARIO :

Lets say there are 100000 rows identified by unique clustering keys per partition. So if i provide both partition key and clustering key in fetch query so, will it load the complete partition into memory in order to traverse through all the clustering keys to find the row specified?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not read the whole partition. It has an index structure. The operating system will cache read and written files, if it has the memory. Therefore if a node has plenty of memory, eventually all the data on that node will be in memory.

Comment: So do you mean that it has indexes over all rows in partition?
And if the partition contains large number of rows, read performance wont be affected?

Comment: @Raedwald Index structure is only for a partition key not for the clustering key.

Comment: There are two separate index structures: an index of partitions, and an index of rows within a partition (when the partition is large enough).

Comment: @TylerHobbs first of all thanks for answer (i guess you are the right person to clear this confusion after looking at your profile :P). I have a related question that, if we have very large number of rows in partition, does the fetch time for a particular row increase as we need some more time to search the correct index among many indexes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Cassandra maintains index and index summary files for only partition key not for clustering key so In order to traverse through all the clustering keys for given partition It will load the data into the memory.

and there is another theory that It will perform the binary search on disk.

Comment: This is incorrect.  For large partitions, there is also an index of rows within the partition.  While Cassandra may have to read some extra rows, it does not have to read the entire partition.

Comment: @TylerHobbs How Cassandra decides that this partition is big enough to maintain the one more index inside the partition too ?

Answer (score 0):

All I was able to find is the **row cache** based on reference in [official wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers).

Not sure if this is same as what was mentioned in previous posts as **row index** or is it something different.

After reading the wiki page I assume that Cassandra does read the whole partition from `SSTable`, in case of a row cache miss. 
When the partition sits in `memtable` the algorithm is different: Cassandra performs a binary search in these cases.

It would be good if someone from this thread could confirm it.